# Render text element on top of group element in svg

Tags: jquery, asp.net, svg

I have a svg map (rendered to dom via jquery) that have group elements that contains one or two path elements.

I want to display some text on top of each group element.

I use jquery to find offset of that group element and created text element by passing the offset.left & offset.top of group element as x&y coordinates to it.

But the text is not displayed on top of the group element. Instead it is displaying somewhere else.

SVG:

```
 <g class="clsTable" id="svg_20">
   <path d="m917.57495,396.125l-0.04999 ..." fill="#919100" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" id="svg_23"/>
   <path d="m916.32501,397.97501l0.09998,2.85001l13.90002,0l0 ..." fill="#FFFF00" clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd" id="svg_26"/>
  </g>
```

Jquery:

```
var x = $("#svg_20").offset().left;
var y = $("#svg_20").offset().top;        
var _text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
_text.setAttribute('x', x);
_text.setAttribute('y', y);
_text.setAttribute('visibility', 'visible');
_text.setAttribute('id', 'lbl');
_text.setAttribute('objectid', "#svg_20");
textNode = document.createTextNode("HI");
_text.appendChild(textNode);
$('svg').append(_text);
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

I tried getBoundingClientRect() for g and getBBox() for child path element. But i am getting object doesnt support this property error in Javascript. Am i doing anything wrong ?...

```
$("#svg_26").getBBox();
```

My application is in asp.net  and target browser is chrome and safari. I am not using canvas element. Instead, am rendering the svg to dom directly inside the innerHtml of main div.

**How to find correct coordinates in jquery and place the label on top
of that group element image?**

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call DOM methods on a jQuery object. Thus the error "object doesnt support this property". You need to call those method on the DOM element directly.

Example:

```
$("#svg_26")[0].getBBox();
// or
$("#svg_26").get(0).getBBox();
```

See: [How do I pull a native DOM element from a jQuery object?](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_pull_a_native_DOM_element_from_a_jQuery_object.3F)